# Warning: truncation from int to char, when using string::find_first_not_of

Tags: c++

We try to clean up our project and remove all warnings.
I get warning for this line:

```
if(line.find_first_not_of('\n\t ') != string::npos) {

warning C4305: 'argument' : truncation from 'int' to 'char'
```

I am not sure what to do... Both values are size_t, not sure why it complains.

Comment: This is a great example of why you should always have your code build without warnings. As Nawaz points out, that find does not do what it looks like it does on a simple reading. When you fix it, I hope you test carefully to ensure that there is no code which depends on the old broken behaviour.

Comment: @Stewart "... always have your code build without warnings." ?!?!? Not sure I'm following that logic. Even a misleading warning is better than just ignoring undefined/unexpected/wrong behavior - it still points to the fact that *something* is weird at that location... Edit: Oh, wait... you probably meant "make sure building your code doesn't drop warnings", not "build your code with warnings disabled"....

Comment: @twalberg - That is exactly what I meant. I meant that your build should be clean of warnings, i.e. when you build it should not generate any warnings. On every project I work on we have warning level set to 4 and treat warnings as errors enabled. That way you can't check in code that generates warnings. We selectively disable warnings we don't like (we have a review process for that).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The warning is misleading. It should rather warn about multi-character to char conversion, as you're using `'\n\t'`(which is multi-character) instead of `"\n\t"` (which is a string).

Anyway, you need to use *double quotes* here:

```
 if(line.find_first_not_of("\n\t ") != string::npos)
```

Hope that helps.